# How TO make Indy 10 TIdTCPClient blocking call?

Tags: delphi, indy10

I have a very simple app, with 10 clients & 2 servers. Each client sends a heartbeat to both servers every 10 seconds. It may also, every few minutes, triggered by an external event, send another string to a TIdCmdTCPServer at the server and wait for a response.

I am a networking novice. To keep matters simple, I would like to make a blocking call (since the system is so simple) - client sends a message to server and blocks, waiting for a reply (or a timeout).

Can I do that? Or do I need to buffer my messages, and wait at the client for a reply (or timeout) before sending the next?

Windows 7 pro, Indy 10, Delphi XE2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indy uses blocking I/O exclusively, so what you are asking for is doable, in fact it is exactly how Indy works under most situations.  Just perform a write operation and wait for it to return, then you can perform a reading operation immediately.  In fact, since you are already using `TIdCmdTCPServer` on the server side, you can use `TIdTCPClient.SendCmd()` on the client side to send a command and wait for its response in a single operation.

Just note that because Indy is blocking, you should use `TIdTCPClient` in a worker thread if you do not want to block your main thread, which would make a UI unresponsive while `TIdTCPClient` is busy.

Comment: +1 and the answer. Thanks, @Remy for confirming this. I will be leaving my TIdTCPClient in the main thread, as I want it to be blocked until the reply is received.